# How to show newlines from textarea in a table?

Tags: html, textarea, newline, line-breaks, tabular

In a form I have a textarea where obviously text is entered. When the input is finished the content gets submitted to the server and is being stored in a database...

When I display the input the user made within a table, the newlines are not visible. When I inspect the source the newlines are there, but within a table the newlines do not work...

Is there any possibility of displaying the linebreaks within that table?
I know, probably a really silly question but I'm not to pro when it comes to things like html and css...

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\n won't be rendered as a new line in HTML. You have to use a `<br/>` to achieve this effect.

Use a string replace to replace all '\n' characters to '`<br/>`'

***If*** you are using a server side language like ***C#*** you can do this

```
private string PutLineBreaks(string strData)
{
    string strReplaced = string.Empty;

    Regex r = new Regex("/\n/g");

    strReplaced = r.Replace(strData, "<br/>");

    return strReplaced;
}
```

Comment: actually, Id rather use a little JavaScript snippet to accomplish that task! anyway, thanks for the info!

Comment: The `\n` is rendered as a newline within `<pre>` tags, or in any block with various settings (e.g. 'pre', 'pre-line') of the `white-space` CSS setting, see e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Answer (score 14):

Set your css in the table cell to

```
white-space:pre-wrap;
```

Comment: It works, and now you can keep `/n` without replacing it to `<br>`. Thanks, *vsync*! P.S. Amazing home page - great job!

Comment: This should be the selected answer. Such a simple way!

Comment: yeah this is the best way

Comment: This is the best answer. In my case `white-space: pre-line;` worked better. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You want to replace all `\n` with `<br/>`.

Answer (score 2):

Set your css in the table cell to

```
white-space:pre-line;
```

Even if your data has trailing spaces it would remove and make data perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`<br />`
, or rather `<p></p>` if we talked about some text and new paragraph. (semantic better solution).

Comment: I'm not sure replacing \n with a <p></p> would be semantically correct actually. <br /> is semantically a line break, as is \n. \n\n however would semantically be a paragraph.

Comment: You'd want to start the entire text block with a '<p>', and close the entire text block with a '</p>'. Then you can replace each '\n' with a '</p><p>', which will close one paragraph and start another.